# How to remember users rating vote

Tags: javascript

```
function toggleText() {

var x = document.getElementById("grade");

if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
} else {
    x.style.display = "block";
}}
```

I have function for displaying paragraph if the user voted on the page to show a paragraph. I want to make a function so if the users reloads the page, his rating to be remembered by the page and the shown paragraph to be there displayed. :)

Comment: localStorage is one way - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Local storage is good if only this browser on this device needs the info.  If you want the server to know about it and for the rating to persist between browser sessions you send the data to the server using a form or AJAX, save the data to a database, and load the data back from the database on new page loads.

Comment: *Where* do you want to voting information to be stored?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options.

Cookies, Session Storage and Local Storage.

[Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie):

> The Document property cookie lets you read and write cookies
> associated with the document. It serves as a getter and setter for the
> actual values of the cookies.

[Session Storage:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

> The read-only sessionStorage property accesses a session Storage
> object for the current origin. sessionStorage is similar to
> localStorage; the difference is that while data in localStorage
> doesn't expire, data in sessionStorage is cleared when the page
> session ends.

[Local Storage:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

> The localStorage read-only property of the window interface allows you
> to access a Storage object for the Document's origin; the stored data
> is saved across browser sessions.
>
> localStorage is similar to sessionStorage, except that while
> localStorage data has no expiration time, sessionStorage data gets
> cleared when the page session ends — that is, when the page is closed.
> (localStorage data for a document loaded in a "private browsing" or
> "incognito" session is cleared when the last "private" tab is closed.)

You could also use PHP Sessions, Save and pull from a database and various other session or storage handling. But they would most likely be total over kill if you don't want to store the rating for anything other than just a single user refreshing a page. Comment me if you intend to actually have Ratings saved by users for viewing tih everyone and I'll update the answer.

But you do want to be careful of [XSS](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/) with something like this.

Update:

Ok so to store the rating for the entire site for any viewer you would want to use Database Storage.

You will have to use a few things here depending on your setup.

First you want to use javascript or form post functionality to send the value to the server side. Lets say PHP which is most likely. you would then have a PHP script store the value onto a database. You have the option of SQL or NoSQL.

[JavaScript XMLHttpRequest:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

> To send an HTTP request, create an XMLHttpRequest object, open a URL,
> and send the request. After the transaction completes, the object will
> contain useful information such as the response body and the HTTP
> status of the result.
>
> ```
> function reqListener () {
>   console.log(this.responseText);
> }
>
>     var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
>     oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
>     oReq.open("GET", "http://www.example.org/example.txt");
>     oReq.send();
> ```

[Sending Via a Form:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data)

> At its most basic, the web uses a client/server architecture that can
> be summarized as follows: a client (usually a web browser) sends a
> request to a server (most of the time a web server like Apache, Nginx,
> IIS, Tomcat, etc.), using the HTTP protocol. The server answers the
> request using the same protocol.

[PHP to Database via MYSQLI:](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

> The mysqli extension allows you to access the functionality provided by MySQL 4.1 and above.

[PHP to Database via PDO:](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

> The PHP Data Objects (PDO) extension defines a lightweight, consistent interface for accessing databases in PHP.

[MariaDB (MySQL):](https://mariadb.org/documentation/)

> The easiest way to understand a database is as a collection of related
> files. Imagine a file (either paper or digital) of sales orders in a
> shop. Then there's another file of products, containing stock records.
> To fulfil an order, you'd need to look up the product in the order
> file and then look up and adjust the stock levels for that particular
> product in the product file. A database and the software that controls
> the database, called a database management system (DBMS), helps with
> this kind of task

[NoSQL :](https://www.mongodb.com/nosql-explained)

> When people use the term “NoSQL database,” they typically use it to
> refer to any non-relational database. Some say the term “NoSQL” stands
> for “non SQL” while others say it stands for “not only SQL.” Either
> way, most agree that NoSQL databases are databases that store data in
> a format other than relational tables.

Comment: I just want the user to see the paragraph that is displayed after they voted. When I vote and refresh the page the paragraph is hidden again...

Comment: I;ve updated for you @AleksandarCvetanovskiRistov